# How can I "verify data after burn" when using Brasero to burn a data DVD?

Tags: brasero

I have been trying Ubuntu for the last couple weeks. I have always used Windows OS in the past. Using Windows I am able to burn backup "data" DVDs and the burning software allows me to "verify data after burn." When activated, after a burn is completed the data that was burned to the disc will be checked for errors. This is important for ensuring that the burned data are the same as what's on the HDD and no errors or corruption has occured.

Can I do this using Ubuntu (Brasero)? I have a folder filled with files and sub-folders that I would like to burn to DVD as a backup to the data I have on the harddrive. But I can't foresee making backup DVDs while using Ubuntu if there's no way to verify the data after the burn is completed.

Answer (score 8):

File and disk image integrity are checked by default in a standard installation of Brasero by comparing an MD5 sum of burned data with the original file.

To change these settings, select *Edit -> Plugins* to open the following window:

[image]

By selecting *Configure* we can change the hashing algortihm for the checksum from **MD5** (default) to **SHA1** or **SHA256**. Unticking the tick box next to a plugin disables checksum generation to speed up the burning process (at the cost of security).

Data integrity can further be checked with *Tools -> Check Integrity* where we are able to select a disc from a list of mounted disks. There we may also import an MD5 file for data comparison.